# Why Database Storing [object object] type

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm trying to uplode File along with some columns.File Uploading sucessfully but why Remaining column taking [object object] type

**Table**

```
public partial class CreateUserIdentity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

**AngularJs**

```
     var description = {
                Passwoed: $scope.FileDescription,
             Email :    $scope.Email
            }
            FileUploadService.UploadFile($scope.SelectedFileForUpload, description

                ).then(function (d) {
});
```

**Mvc Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
         public JsonResult SaveFiles(string description)
       {
           if (Request.Files != null)
           {
              CreateUserIdentity f = new CreateUserIdentity
                   {
                       Image = actualFileName,
                        Email = description,
                   };
                   using (ProjectsEntities dc = new ProjectsEntities())
                   {
                       dc.CreateUserIdentities.Add(f);
                       dc.SaveChanges();
                       Message = "File uploaded successfully";
                       flag = true;
                   }
               }

 return new JsonResult { Data = new { Message = Message, Status = flag } };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `description` you are sending is not a `string` - it is an object consisting of `Email` and `Passwoed` - type that correctly in your rest-controller and use `Email = description.Email`

Alertatively you can just send `$scope.Email` from the angular-side instead of wrapping it in a `description`-Object, that should work as well (if you don't need the attribute `Passwoed`).